# Exchange 2010 remote access

Tags: exchange, remote-access, windows-sbs-2008, outlook-web-app

Does anyone know how to configure more addresses for remote access to Outlook on our SBS 2008? Currently you can go to either 'https://remote.site.co.uk/remote' to acces the remote web workspace or 'https://remote.site.co.uk/owa' to go straight to remote exchange access. I would like to set it up so that by going to 'https://remote.site.co.uk/exchange' it takes you to same place that '/owa' would. Does anybody know if this is possible, and if so how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /owa or /exchange part of your URL is the name of the virtual directory that your Outlook Web Access site is running under. You can create new OWA virtual directorys, with whatever name you want to give them, by running this command in the Exchange shell.

```
New-OwaVirtualDirectory -Name "Virtual Directory Name" -WebSite "website name"
```

so in your case, assuming you are using the default website, you would run:

```
New-OwaVirtualDirectory -Name "Exchange" -WebSite "Default Web Site"
```

Comment: James, if Sam answered your question and it is working, please mark his answer as the accepted answer.